# Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4

Tags: php, regex

Hola muy buenas :) estoy estudiando Regex en PHP pero me sale el error Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4 ¿Qué podría ser?

```
<?php
echo (preg_match("/^[\w-_.]{0,}@[\w]{0,}(\.[A-z]{2,}){1,}$/i","Correo@gmail.com"));
?>
```

Ya intente cambiarle el delimitador, las banderas, etc....(de echo en la bandera trate de poner la g de global uy no lo reconoce) y ninguna funciona :(

Comment: No tiene ningún error que evite compilarlo el regex... ¿seguro de que no te olvidaste copiar un caracter a la pregunta? De todas formas, el error es claro, te dice que el guión `-` está formando un rango inválido, o sea que es algo como `Z-A` que sería ilógico... Se arregla escapando con `\-`

Comment: La `/g` se usa en otros lenguajes. En PHP para múltiples coincidencias se usa `preg_match_all()`

Comment: Yo [no lo puedo reproducir](https://rextester.com/MFVI51453)

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el mensaje de error, tiene un rango no válido `\w-_`. Dado que el rango `\w-_` no tiene sentido, debe haber querido decir que el signo menos es parte del conjunto de caracteres. Como `-` tiene un significado especial en los conjuntos de caracteres (que definen rangos), debe escaparse o ir al final. Aunque, según @Pollo, eso no pudo haber causado el error.

Además, el guión bajo ya está incluido en `\w`.

También puede reemplazar `{0,}` con `*`, aunque definitivamente quiso decir `{1,}`, que se reemplaza con `+`.

Por lo tanto:

```php
<?php
echo (preg_match('/^[\w.-]+@\w+(\.[a-z]{2,})+$/i',"Correo@gmail.com"));
?>
```

Además, no es así como se validan los correos electrónicos en PHP. Consulte https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php.
Disculpe mi español menos que perfecto.

Comment: @Pollo, exactamente, pero el autor obviamente no pretendía crear un rango.

Comment: Estamos de acuerdo (lee el comentario que le dejé en la pregunta antes de que respondas). Además, está mostrando un error con `preg_match_all()` pero muestra el código de `preg_match()`... Y además insisto: `[\w-_]` de ninguna manera genera un rango. Esto está especificado en PCRE, que sólo se crean rangos desde caracteres. Un guión que sigue a un shorthand se toma como lliteral

Comment: *it must be escaped with a backslash or appear in a position where it cannot be interpreted as indicating a range, typically as the first or last character in the class, or immediately after a range* Fuente: https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC9

Comment: Es interesante. Sospeché un problema con la barra invertida por un tiempo. Quizás, el ejemplo está sobreadaptado. De todos modos, `-` al final de la clase de caracteres es la mejor práctica.

Comment: Estoy convencido de que el autor está copiando un línea que no es la que le genera el error. Y también el texto "tiene un rango no válido `\w-_`" en tu respuesta es incorrecto por lo que comenté arriba